# How display new xml layout with callback by JS (Android Studio)?

Tags: android

I have a problem with callback by JS script and Webview.

This my code:

JS:

```
echo <<<JSCRIPT
<script>
Android.loadStatus('Success');
</script>
JSCRIPT;
```

And Java:

```
public class WebAppInterface extends Activity {
        Context mContext;

        /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        /** Show a toast from the web page */
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void loadStatus(String status) {
            if(status.equals("Success")){
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

                mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
                mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                mWebView.clearCache(true);
                mWebView.loadUrl("SomeUrl");

                FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
                fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Snackbar.make(view, authkeyCookie, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .setAction("Action", null).show();
                    }
                });

                DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
                ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
                drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
                toggle.syncState();

                NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
                navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener((NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener) this);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(mContext, status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }
```

After run, I have nothing... setContentView is not working.

Actually I need to reload function onCreate when I get callback by JS.
Help :)

Comment: Where is your `onCreate`? And what do you want to reload exactly? Do you perhaps want to update some views based on the value from your JS script? Does the `loadStatus(String status)` at least get called?

Comment: onCreate is started with `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Comment: No, that is not correct.  Add the `onCreate` method in your WebAppInterface activity and in there you can call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`.

Comment: On create in webappinterface? Its impossible?

Comment: The onCreate method (part of your Activity lifecycle) has to be outside of the `public void loadStatus(String status)` - and since it is a lifecycle method - you do not call it yourself. Actually, you should move the entire code that you have under the `if(status.equals("Success"))` - to your `onCreate` method - I have created [a Gist here as example](https://gist.github.com/ishmaelmakitla/97dd7e5c8bf61627fed747a550d5bec5).

Comment: Look, I want load two XML layout, one loading by default, and second will load when js send call back from first layout. Your answer is applicability for me? Thanks

Comment: This code `Toast.makeText(mContext, status, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` is working fine, but if I try reload activity, I got nothing..

Comment: Please read about [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) - this seems to be what you want to do - you can replace a `Fragment` when you "reload" - you should not using `setContentView` for that. Another option is to load a different `Activity` altogether when you get "success" from your JS script - see here a guide on [starting another activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).